# Using GMSH python API to mesh a step file and save the resulting msh file to disk

Tags: python, gmsh

I have a large number of step files from which I want to extract the mesh information using GMSH's python API. I am following [this](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/blob/gmsh_4_8_4/tutorial/python/t20.py) tutorial to load and manipulate a STEP file in the official documentation page of gmsh but it makes slices before generating the mesh.

However, I just want to load a step file and generate its 3D mesh and save the mesh file to the disk without any manipulation.

How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```py
import gmsh
gmsh.initialize()
gmsh.option.setNumber("General.Terminal", 1)
gmsh.model.add("modelo_1")

gmsh.merge("FileName.step")


gmsh.model.mesh.generate(3)

gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()
gmsh.fltk.run()
gmsh.finalize()
```

https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#index-gmsh_002fmerge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).